# How do I reset some of the object's properties to their initial value?

Tags: objective-c

Suppose I have an object "dog" of class "Dog" whose properties can be divided into two groups:

(A) properties that must be initialized only once, when dog is allocated;
 (B) properties that must be re-initialized (reset) every once in a while;

So I need a method "resetB" which resets properties in group (B) using self, i.e.

```
-(void) resetB {
    self.propB1 = initValB1;
    self.propB2 = initValB2;
    self.propB3 = initValB3;
}
```

In order to avoid duplicated code (the actual situation is much more complicated, with tens of properties) I'd like to call "resetB" from my "init", so that init wuold look like this

```
-(id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if ( self ) {
        propA1 = initValA1;
        propA2 = initValA2;
        propA3 = initValA3;
        [self resetB];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Ok, but now I'm worried that I'm messaging "self" from my "init" method, which people say is considered... "impolite"... (so to speak).
My questions are: do I worry too much about etiquette, and it is actually safe to do as above? Or, maybe, duplicate code (which must be kept in sync) is the lesser evil? Or there is another "correct" way of doing this?

Comment: It's entirely safe to send messages to `self` in an `init` method. Wherever did you hear otherwise? You may have heard not to _leak_ self. This is different.

Comment: In my experience, if I see someone setting a property directly (not using the property setter). I assume that it must be for a reason. Even in the init method.

Comment: @CrimsonChris, thanks for your comments. The place where I "heard otherwise" is developer.apple.com. It says: "You should always access the instance variables directly from within an initialization method because..." You can easily find the relevant web page.

Comment: I prefer to never use KVO (it's evil) and just make custom setters nil safe. It's simpler than cluttering up the init method with nil checks for self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the only reason it's considered *potentially dangerous* to call methods on `self` from within `init` is when you are calling a property setter or another method where KVO could cause side-effects.

If you know that method won't cause side-effects then it's safe to call, and it's pretty normal to call a common "setup method" from multiple versions of `init` or from `awakeFromNib` etc.

**EDIT** As mentioned by @sergio another reason to avoid calling a method on `self` from `init` is that it could be overridden by a subclass which is not properly initialised.  One way around that is to put the reset implementation into a private method, which is called from `init` and have the public method use the private method also.  While the private method *could* also be overridden, it should be obvious that it shouldn't have been:

```
@interface MyClass ()
- (void)_resetB;
@end

@implementation MyClass

-(id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if ( self ) {
        _propA1 = initValA1;
        _propA2 = initValA2;
        _propA3 = initValA3;
        [self _resetB];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)resetB
{
    [self _resetB];
}

#pragma mark - Private Methods

- (void)_resetB
{
    _propB1 = initValB1;
    _propB2 = initValB2;
    _propB3 = initValB3;
}

@end
```

Comment: This is not entirely correct. The risk also lays with calling a method overridden in a derived class; in this case, the derived class implementation would be executed inside of a non-fully initialised object.

Comment: @sergio Yeah that would cause problems and calling a private method would certainly make it safer (and getting the public method to call through to the private method as well), as you suggest in your answer.

Comment: In the end it comes down to the same kind of problem as with KVO. The only thing I do not understand is who downvoted my answer... but it is nice to see that you find it on spot! Thanks.

Comment: @sergio It looks like the up/down voter has changed their mind on both our answers.  Time to get on with something rewarding, like real life :)

Comment: thanks, both your and @trojanfoe 's answers very clear and helpful. I'm fairly new to objc (and OO in general) and sometimes I feel the presence of a "vague impalpable layer" which makes me want to go back to assembly languange... :)

Answer (score 2):

Sending a message to `self` from `init` is safe when two conditions are met:

- the method you are calling is not overridden by a derived class -- in which case the derived class implementation would be called before the object is fully initialised;
- you are not setting a property, which could trigger some action on the same object (which would still be non-fully initialised) through KVO.

If your `reset` method (non associated to setting properties) is meant to be private, there should no problem with it, unless someone defines a method with the same name in a derived class.

To reduce this risk further, you can use a naming convention for your private methods e.g., `_resetB`.